# Should there be a comma in this context?

Tags: commas

> Louis XIV, the Sun King
>
> Thor, the God of Thunder

In this kind of structure, should there be a comma before its nickname?

Comment: Can you explain why you think there would/wouldn't be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar used is called an *appositive*.

From [the Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html) (I have had to remove the differently coloured text—since it can't be reproduced here; I am using italics to represent the noun or pronoun and bold italics to represent the appositive):

> An appositive is a noun or pronoun — often with modifiers — set beside another noun or pronoun to explain or identify it. Here are some examples of appositives (the noun or pronoun will be in [*italics*], the appositive will be in [***bold italics***]).
>
> - Your *friend* ***Bill*** is in trouble.
> - My brother's *car*, ***a sporty red convertible with bucket seats***, is the envy of my friends.
> - The chief *surgeon*, ***an expert in organ-transplant procedures***, took her nephew on a hospital tour.
>
> An appositive phrase usually follows the word it explains or identifies, but it may also precede it.
>
> - ***A bold innovator***, *Wassily Kandinsky* is known for his colorful abstract paintings.
> - ***The first state to ratify the U. S. Constitution***, *Delaware* is rich in history.
> - ***A beautiful collie***, *Skip* was my favorite dog.

Note that the use or omission of commas is due to whether the appositive information is nonrestrictive or restrictive—not simply because an appositive is used.

---

If, for example, there were five people named Thor in a room and only one of them was the God of Thunder, then you would need to use a *restrictive* appositive—without a comma:

> Of the five Thors present, Thor the God of Thunder was the first to get angry, but Thor the salesman was the eventual winner of the argument.

It's when there's only a single person named Thor among the group that a *nonrestrictive* appositive, with a comma, is used.

---

In the example sentences in the question, it's likely there's only one person in the discussion named Louis XIV, or one person named Thor, so a comma is fine. However if there *were* at least two people in the discussion with one of those names, then the comma should be removed.

---

Note, too, that there is a difference between a *name* and a *title*.

For example, Thor might go by the name (or nickname) *Thor the Magnificent*. In that case, there is no appositive because the entire phrase is what he is using to call himself. Even though the components of the nickname are made up of a given name and a title joined together, the result is a compound proper noun—rather than a proper noun followed by an appositive.

This makes an analogous distinction between his full name (a proper noun), *Thor Odinson*, and a title or description of himself (using a nonrestrictive appositive) that follows his first name:  *Thor, the son of Odin*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the examples are correct. Before introducing someone’s title, i.e. The Sun King, God of Thunder, there should be a pause, which the comma serves as.